# Плагин карусели

Tags: jquery, плагин, карусель

Подскажите, пожалуйста, jQuery плагин для быстрого развёртывания такой карусели
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам нашёл подходящий http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/index.php

Answer (score -1):

Найти можете на сайте http://phpdesigner.in.ua/jquery/

[Minimit Gallery](http://phpdesigner.in.ua/jquery/50-jquery-css-resheniy-dlya-veb-razrabotchikov/)

[Анимированная jQuery карусель](http://phpdesigner.in.ua/jquery/pervaya-podborka-jquery-css-resheniy-dlya-veb-razrabotchikov-v-2012-godu/)

[Плагин jQuery «Scroller»](http://phpdesigner.in.ua/jquery/pervaya-podborka-jquery-css-resheniy-dlya-veb-razrabotchikov-v-2012-godu/)

[jQuery карусель 3D](http://phpdesigner.in.ua/jquery/novye-slaydery-akkordeony-i-slayd-shou-jquery-resheniya-dlya-veb-razrabotchikov/)

В разделе есть еще много интересных решений для веб